# Release build behaves differently then debugging from Flash Builder

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, apache-flex, flash-builder

Is it possible that stuff that works while debugging from the flash builder simply work differently when exporting a release build?

For instance, i have this:

```
private function getErrorText(error:Error):String{
            var result:String = "";
            result = "FehlerArt: " + error.name + "//" + (error.message as String).substring(0, (error.message as String).indexOf(":")) +  "\n";
            result += "Fehler: " + (error.message as String).substring((error.message as String).indexOf(":") + 1) + "\n";
            result += "Komponente: " + getComponentID();
            return result;
        }
```

When i execute this using the debugger im Flash builder, i get the correct string:

```
FehlerArt: ReferenceError//Error #1065
Fehler:  Variable mistake is not defined.
Komponente: button1
```

But if i do the same thing using a exported release build, i get this:

```
FehlerArt: ReferenceError//
Fehler: Error #1065
Komponente: button1
```

So it looks like the message in the Error class is differently formated when executing a release build, and there are other examples too.

So is there some kind of configuratrion which i have to set to make the release execution the same as the debugging execution?

**UPDATE**

While the solution from divillysausages works, it will not show specific info, for instance, if there is an "variable mistake not defined", it will say "variable /n not defined", and if the code is huge, it will be a problem for the user. So is there any way to export the app as an debug build?

I tried exporting it like a release build, and then replace the SWF in the install directory with the SWF in my bin-debug directory, and the application works, but it will still not show all information about an error if one happens

Answer (score 2):

This is expected behaviour - the message you're getting in debug mode is fully fleshed out, simply because all of the debug symbols are available. In release, they're removed for speed reasons.

You can check out the docs on Error here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Error.html but it pretty much specifies that it's main usage is in debug mode (full message, error dialog box, full stack trace etc).

Generally, what'd you do in this case, is to catch the error, then log a message using whatever logging system you have in place. That way you can customise the message to your exact needs. You can check out all the runtime error ids here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/runtimeErrors.html

**Update**

I wrote a class that scrapes the above link to display runtime errors dynamically, so you don't need to write out custom messages for each one. You can get it here: http://divillysausages.com/blog/making_sense_of_as3_runtime_errors_at_runtime

Also included in an XML file containing all the current errors (as of today)

Comment: So, you are suggesting i write my own error messages depending on the error code which is provided even in the release build? Is there maybe a way to turn on the full error message option in the release? In my application, the user may write and run his own code, and when he makes an error, then an error must pop up, so u see how writinge my own message for every error could be annoying?  But if there is no other way, i will do it

Comment: I'm not entirely sure that you can export a release build with the debug symbols enabled; otherwise it would just be a debug build :) So you can either do that, or wait a bit, as your question made me think that it should be possible to scrape the errors page in real-time. I should be able to upload the code this evening

Comment: There is another problem, when there is an error like "variable mistake not defined", then it will say "variable /n not defined", and thats a bit of a problem, cuz if the code is huge, then the error is hard to find for the user, so i think i will need to enable debug options in my release build, any idea how to do that?

Comment: wierd, i tried exporting a release, install it, then replace the normal SWF in the install directory from the SWF in my bin-debug dir of my project, and the application works, but i still dont get all error info when an error happens

Comment: "cuz if the code is huge, then the error is hard to find for the user" - you can also call `getStackTrace()` on the `Error` object to get the call stack so the user can have an idea of where the error occurred. In debug builds, this will include the line number. As for exporting debug/release builds, what are you using to code?

Comment: "but i still dont get all error info when an error happens" - as well as being a debug build, you also need to be testing in the debug flash player (this includes your end user - if they're running the normal flash player, then they'll just get the release info). All the different downloads that you needs are here: http://www.adobe.com/support/flashplayer/downloads.html

Comment: BTW, I updated the code to fix an unrelated bug, if you want to re-download it